# how to avoid python formatting from rounding floating point

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
limited="{:0.{}f}".format(0.32244647, 5)
print (limited)
```

it shows `'0.32245'`. i expected it to only limit the floating digits by 5 not round them. 
I need to have `0.3224`. i used `round` function as well but its function was like this.

Comment: It's kind of surprising that the formatting isn't flexible enough to let you do this directly.

Comment: when doing `format(myFloat, ".5f")` it will round because of  the purpose of precision.  It wants to give you the most  accurate information.  If you are looking to just truncate the float, you would need to do:   `math.floor(myFloat * PLACES) / PLACES`  where PLACES is 10\*\*the number of places (10\*\*5) in your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: @Fallenreaper I would use `math.trunc` rather than `math.floor`, it produces the expected result with negative numbers.

Comment: Good call @MarkRansom